# PyGTK in webbrowser?

Tags: python, web, gtk, pygtk

I use PyGTK quite a lot, and my code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/ralphembree).  I know that there are many websites that can run Python code, but I was hoping that maybe there is a website that can handle the new windows created in my code in the browser, so that people could test my code without needing to download it.  Is there such a website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

If you switch to Python 3 and `from gi.repository import Gtk`, then you can use [Broadway](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-broadway.html) to run a GTK application in your browser. However, this only works locally, not as a website.